# Gray grid on google map

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have created a map which you can see here http://summitaccounting.ca/about-us

I have created the API key twice with the same result

I have pinpointed the property. However, I cannot get rid of the gray grid over the top of the map. Here is the code I am using.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 52.115, lng: -114.894};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_fWUOsy0ygeKqSbdfiaK7_WKCrXCkDgc&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I removed that reference and added the padding in the bootstrap-default-min.css.

Answer (score 1):

In your template.css file, you have this style declaration:

```
a img,fieldset,img{
    border:none;
    padding:5px 10px !important;
}
```

It's that padding that is messing with your google maps.  You're going to need to rework some of this, or try to override it with even more `!important` styles for the google maps.  ugh.